# WordPress internal Server Error 500 when moving hosts

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, wp-admin

I am trying to move my WordPress site from one hosting service to another. I made a backup and restored it on the new host. But I am getting internal server 500 error on the site. I have tried to fix the `.htaccess` file but its still giving error.

The issue is, if I try to rename it to test it, its not giving the internal 500 error but redirecting me to WordPress installation page called wp-admin/install.php

Can someone help me for solve the issue.Thanks

Comment: "HTTP 500" is generic - it doesn't tell you much besides "something went wrong, somewhere on the server".  You want to look at your system logs to determine *WHAT* went wrong.  You need more information *ABOUT* the problem in order to *RESOLVE* the problem.

Comment: Can you please make DEBUG : true in wp-config.php file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the suggestions that are given are great, but if those do not work, then you can try to downgrade PHP. It had worked in my case when I was facing the same error.

Answer (score 0):

You can dig in the error log and find what exactly is causing the error. 
Steps for debug.
As previously said:  stop all plugins and try again. If problem still exists check logs again. Then switch to default  theme and so on.

Btw have moved the DB properly? With the same connection settings.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check your wp-config.php and PHP version. make sure you have entered correct DB info in wp-config like db_name, password, and table_prefix etc...

Comment: Thanks this helped me to make my site live. it worked perfect.

Answer (score 0):

if You have changed hosting, probable You need to check `database and .htacess` file. If You are getting installation page means its database issue, Please check database `prefix` in `wp-config.php` file and it will solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

there are lot of causes for internal server error. The main reasons for internal server errors are.

1. Corrupt .htaccess file
2. PHP Memory limit
3. Faulty code in Theme
4. Corrupted plugin
5. Corrupted core files
6. Incompatible PHP version

In oder to fix this issue, you need to investigate in step by step order.

To solve this issue first of all you need to enable **Debug mode** and check the issue. 
 after that try with restoring .htacess file, enabling default theme, disabling plugins etc.

if you still facing 500 internal server issue, follow [tutorial on WPERA to fix 500 internal server error](https://www.wpera.net/500-internal-server-error/). Hope this helps.